# Version control for MySQL objects (panoramic templates)

Tags: mysql, git, versioning, view-templates

I am building a multi-tenant system that uses the wonderful [panoramic gem](https://github.com/apeacox/panoramic) to store HAML view templates in a MySQL table.

I often edit these templates (body, text) and would like some kind of version control system so that I can diff, rollback, view history, etc. the template content (rather than losing the changes and history forever). Something that uses a Git GUI tool (GitHub, RubyMine, etc.) would be ideal.

Is there some way to store the template objects in a Git repo, and have MySQL automagically refer to the versioned object as though it was in the db?

I can do a mysqldump every day, but that seems cumbersome to diff, etc.

Any ideas would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Ruby 2.1.5, Rails 3.2.21, MySQL 5.6